# No Guarda conexion Bluetooth a la impresora

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth, impresión

Buenas tardes

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación movil en android studio en la cual debo de imprimir ticket por medio de bluetooth a una impresora movil de la marca CITIZE.

Ya hago la conexión a la impresora y ya imprimo, pero no se por que razon no me guarda esa conexión a la impresora, si me salgo del activity de donde hago la conexión a la impresora ya no puedo mandar a imprimir nada por que se desconecta la conexión a la impresora.

Les dejo mi código donde hago la conexión bluetooth

```
package mx.com.oncontrol.printer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.citizen.port.android.BluetoothPort;
import com.citizen.request.android.RequestHandler;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Created by ONC-LAP on 24/11/2016.
 */

public class ConexionBluet extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectMenu";
    // Intent request codes
    // private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private Vector<BluetoothDevice> remoteDevices;
    private BroadcastReceiver searchFinish;
    private BroadcastReceiver searchStart;
    private BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult;
    private Thread hThread;
    private Context context;

    // UI
    private Button btnlista;
    private EditText btAddrBox;
    private Button connectButton;
    private Button searchButton;
    private ListView list;
    // BT
    //private BluetoothPort bluetoothPort;
    private BluetoothPort bluetoothPort;

    // Activar Bluetooth en Caso de Estar Inactivo
    private void bluetoothSetup()
    {
        // Initialize
        clearBtDevData();
        bluetoothPort = BluetoothPort.getInstance();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            return;
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }



    private static final String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "//temp";
    private static final String fileName = dir + "//BTPrinter";
    private String lastConnAddr;
    private void loadSettingFile()
    {
        int rin = 0;
        char [] buf = new char[128];
        try
        {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            rin = fReader.read(buf);
            if(rin > 0)
            {
                lastConnAddr = new String(buf,0,rin);
                btAddrBox.setText(lastConnAddr);
            }
            fReader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection history not exists.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void saveSettingFile()
    {
        try
        {
            File tempDir = new File(dir);
            if(!tempDir.exists())
            {
                tempDir.mkdir();
            }
            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
            if(lastConnAddr != null)
                fWriter.write(lastConnAddr);
            fWriter.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    // clear device data used list.
    private void clearBtDevData()
    {
        remoteDevices = new Vector<BluetoothDevice>();
    }
    // add paired device to list
    private void addPairedDevices()
    {
        BluetoothDevice pairedDevice;
        Iterator<BluetoothDevice> iter = (mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()).iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            pairedDevice = iter.next();
            remoteDevices.add(pairedDevice);
            adapter.add(pairedDevice.getName() +"\n["+pairedDevice.getAddress()+"] [Paired]");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_menu);
        // Setting
        btAddrBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextAddressBT);
        connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonConnectBT);
        searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSearchBT);
        btnlista = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_lista);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        context = this;
        // Setting
        loadSettingFile();
        bluetoothSetup();

        //Ir a LA LISTA

        btnlista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConexionBluet.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // Connect, Disconnect -- Button
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(!bluetoothPort.isConnected()) // Connect routine.
                {
                    try
                    {
                        btConn(mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btAddrBox.getText().toString()));
                    }
                    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {
                        // Bluetooth Address Format [OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO]
                        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
                        AlertView.showAlert(e.getMessage(), context);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
                        AlertView.showAlert(e.getMessage(), context);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else // Disconnect routine.
                {
                    // Always run.
                    btDisconn();
                }
            }
        });
        // Search Button
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
                {
                    clearBtDevData();
                    adapter.clear();
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }
                else
                {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }
        });
        // Bluetooth Device List
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        addPairedDevices();
        // Connect - click the List item.
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                BluetoothDevice btDev = remoteDevices.elementAt(arg2);
                try
                {
                    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
                    {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("MacImpresora",btDev.getAddress());
                    editor.commit();
                    btAddrBox.setText(settings.getString("MacImpresora",""));
                    btConn(btDev);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    AlertView.showAlert(e.getMessage(), context);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        // UI - Event Handler.
        // Search device, then add List.
        discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                String key;
                BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(remoteDevice != null)
                {
                    if(remoteDevice.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
                    {
                        key = remoteDevice.getName() +"\n["+remoteDevice.getAddress()+"]";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        key = remoteDevice.getName() +"\n["+remoteDevice.getAddress()+"] [Paired]";
                    }
                    remoteDevices.add(remoteDevice);
                    adapter.add(key);
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        searchStart = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                connectButton.setEnabled(false);
                btAddrBox.setEnabled(false);
                searchButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_stop_search_btn));
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(searchStart, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        searchFinish = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                connectButton.setEnabled(true);
                btAddrBox.setEnabled(true);
                searchButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_search_btn));
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(searchFinish, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        try
        {
            saveSettingFile();
            bluetoothPort.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        if((hThread != null) && (hThread.isAlive()))
        {
            hThread.interrupt();
            hThread = null;
        }
        unregisterReceiver(searchFinish);
        unregisterReceiver(searchStart);
        unregisterReceiver(discoveryResult);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private connTask connectionTask;
    // Bluetooth Connection method.
    private void btConn(final BluetoothDevice btDev) throws IOException
    {
        if((connectionTask != null) && (connectionTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
        {
            connectionTask.cancel(true);
            if(!connectionTask.isCancelled())
                connectionTask.cancel(true);
            connectionTask = null;
        }
        connectionTask = new connTask();
        connectionTask.execute(btDev);
    }
    // Bluetooth Disconnection method.
    private void btDisconn()
    {
        try
        {
            bluetoothPort.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        if((hThread != null) && (hThread.isAlive()))
            hThread.interrupt();
        // UI
        connectButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dev_conn_btn));
        list.setEnabled(true);
        btAddrBox.setEnabled(true);
        searchButton.setEnabled(true);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.bt_disconn_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    // Bluetooth Connection Task.
    class connTask extends AsyncTask<BluetoothDevice, Void, Integer>
    {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ConexionBluet.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_tab));
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.connecting_msg));
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(BluetoothDevice... params)
        {
            Integer retVal = null;
            try
            {
                bluetoothPort.connect(params[0]);
                lastConnAddr = params[0].getAddress();
                retVal = Integer.valueOf(0);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                retVal = Integer.valueOf(-1);
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {
            if(result.intValue() == 0)  // Connection success.
            {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                hThread = new Thread(rh);
                hThread.start();
                // UI
                connectButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dev_disconn_btn));
                list.setEnabled(false);
                btAddrBox.setEnabled(false);
                searchButton.setEnabled(false);
                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.bt_conn_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            else    // Connection failed.
            {
                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                AlertView.showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_conn_fail_msg),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.dev_check_msg), context);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar

Comment: La conexión se pierde por que mandas a imprimir desde el activity, y al salir del activity este o se destruye o simplemente se manda a dormir, por lo que necesitas crear un servicio asincrono en segundo plano.

Comment: TENDRAS ALGUN EJEMPLO LA VERDAD NO SE COMO SE HACE UN SERVICIO Y MENOS CON BLUETOOTH

Comment: No tengo un ejemplo hecho por mí te paso una página que te puede orientar. http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/ y por favor para la próxima vez procura escribir con minúsculas, ya que se considera ofensivo las mayúsculas

Comment: deja lo reviso, una disculpa por las mayusculas